# binomial identity involving products

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Let $k\in\mathbb{N}$. We denote by $\binom{x}{k}$ the polynomial $\frac{x(x-1)\ldots(x-k+1)}{k!}\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$. I would like to know if $\binom{xy}{k}$ can be written as a polynomial in $\binom{x}{1},\ldots,\binom{x}{k}$, $\binom{y}{1},\ldots,\binom{y}{k}$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. In other words, I want to know if there exists a polynomial $\phi\in \mathbb{Z}[U_1,\ldots,U_{2k}]$ such that 
$$\binom{xy}{k}=\phi\left(\binom{x}{1},\ldots,\binom{x}{k},\binom{y}{1},\ldots,\binom{y}{k}\right)$$

Comment: Since your coefficients include $x$ and $y$ how could it fail to be?

Comment: As Igor indicates, you mean "polynomial in [blah] with coefficients in $\bf Z$" (not $\Bbb Z[x,y]$). It is completely clear to me what you're asking; voting to close in order to vote to reopen.

Comment: I have cheked this for $k=2,3$ and it works but it is not clear how I could work in the general case.